# Ending a measure in “and!”

Tags: theory, piano, time-signatures

I am transposing Nocturne Op.9 into 3/4 instead of 12/8. In one of the measures it counts one-and-a-two-and-a-three-and. I am not sure if this is allowed because I am self-taught. Is this OK or do I have to re-do my entire piece?

Comment: I'm guessing this is Chopin, Op. 9/2 in E-flat?

Comment: you are going to have a very hard time turning 3 into 4

Comment: Iv’e already started

Comment: What you are aiming is not entirely unheard of, you are in essence trying to give a piece a swing beat, just keep it to three time, so just pick 9/8

Comment: @NeilMeyer - trying to give a swing beat, one more often goes from 4/4 to 12/8 either physically, or with the equivalent quaver/triplet sign at the top of the sheet. By going straight into 3/4, and doubling the value of each note, it'll work fine. 9/8 won't really work, from 12/8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, 3/4 and 12/8 are completely different to start with. You seem to know that Compound time is counted differently (from the comments section), You have to understand that Time Signatures, although only used to keep time most of the time in a non-classical context, matters significantly in genre of music. Not just in counting but also the way music is felt. i'd suggest that you read up more on Time signature.

And for your question, you have to mention the context. Sometimes bars end without full measure's counts ending because of anacrusis (up beat).

If you are talking about Op.9 No.2, It starts with an anacrusis of 1 quaver. So At the last bar of a section, bar will be short of 1 quaver.

Comment: That is the answer I needed I wasn’t sure if I could end it one and or if it had to be exactly on three.

Answer (score 1):

Neck on the line here! It could have, quite conceivably, been written in 3/4. Double the value of each note, and it will fit fine. It's usually played with such rubato that the 12/8 rhythm becomes a little lost anyway.

By splitting each bar into four separate bars, it has to work.